# Doctrine Searchable vs. Mysql Fulltext

Tags: mysql, full-text-search, doctrine

I have  a CSV file will 3x10^6 rows, title and body mostly, the text
file has 3GB+.

Im a little scared of the fact that Seachable will almost duplicate
the data, can anyone please advise me on the advantages of searchable
over a mysql fulltext index on the title, body columns?

Comment: *3x10^6 rows* - couldn't you just write *3 mln rows*? :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After detailed investigation, I found that the search functions are not fully implemented in Doctrine.

So, if you use Searchable, you just only get an index table. After that, you should write your own functions to use that table with complex search queries. Doctrine only provides a basic search function, which can only search one keyword. (By the way I am talking about Doctrine 1.2, I am not sure what does Doctrine 2.0 have).

On the other hand, MySQL Fulltext search has everything you need. You can even use boolean searches easily.